# Google Sign In Auto Fails

Tags: java, android, google-signin

I have 3 devices that I test this on. Moto G 1st gen (4.4.4), Moto G 2nd gen (5.0.1), Nexus 5 (6.0.1). All of them are on the same wifi network. The following code works perfectly on the Moto G 1st gen, but fails automatically on the other two. Even when using different accounts.

I have also tested this in an emulator running android 6.0 same issue. Please help.

Log:

```
D/Google Account: handleSignInResult: false
```

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java - onCreate

```
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build();
GAPIclient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this,this)
     .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
     .build();
signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(GAPIclient);
if (logged_in){
   GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(signInIntent);
    if (result != null){
         acct = result.getSignInAccount();
    }
}
```

onStart, onStop, signIn, signOut (called by button press)

```
@Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
       GAPIclient.connect();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (GAPIclient.isConnected()) {
        GAPIclient.disconnect();
    }
}
public void signIn(){
     Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(GAPIclient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
public void signOut(){
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(GAPIclient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
        }
    });
    logged_in = false;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("logged_in", false);
    editor.commit();
    accountFragment.makeSignIn();
}`
```

onActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
```

handle signin result

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()){
       ...
```

**UPDATE**

Same result now on moto g after I attempted to add a second SHA1 key to the credentials.

Comment: Please format the code. This is a lot of code, please write a minified version of the issue.

Comment: Done. I hope it is good

Comment: @CyberGeek.exe I have same problem. You already know the answer?

Comment: @E-Place yes. Please see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put both the debug and release SHA1 keys in the Google credentials page.

Reason: for some reason it is not consistent when in debug mode about which key it sends. It is apparently device based. Oh, mother Google...